# Input type=email's change event is not firing when the value entered is whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, addeventlistener

I've added an on 'change' event listener to a `type=email` input element. When I add a couple space characters into the email field, then lose focus on that element, the change event doesn't seem to be firing.

However, this exact scenario works just fine with `type=text` input elements.

What's going on?

```
$('input[type="email"]').change(e => {
    console.log('Triggered!');
});
```

Browser: Chrome Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Are spaces allowed in an email address? *(Not a question.. Just sarcasm...)*

Comment: So... What are you trying to accomplish? Custom validation?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I want to add my own custom-styled error messages that checks the field before the form is submitted. I wanted to use the change listener because it won't validate if the user just tabs over the field, only when they actually enter a value. Using the blur listener is an alternative - I just find it slightly annoying the field throws an error if it loses focus.

Comment: I suggest you use loseFocus since the change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus

Comment: Plus you would make a query every letter sent when you know that the email wont be valid until the 2 last character are typed in  like  .uk would make a_simple_user@somewhere.uk

Your onChange would only return a valid status after the email if fully typed in.

Answer (score 3):

I originally said that it looks like there is an automatic `trim` operation performed on email fields because the length of the value is coming back at 0 after typing some spaces and leaving the field, but upon returning to the field, the spaces remain in the element, so they aren't getting trimmed out.

I suspect that, because spaces are not valid for this input type, they are not considered part of the value, thus the value doesn't change when you enter them and the `change` event doesn't fire.

Type some spaces in the field and then hit TAB to leave the field, but then return to the field. The spaces will still be there.

```js
$('input[type="email"]').on("blur", function(e){
  console.log(this.value.length);
});

$('input[type="email"]').on("change", function(e){
  console.log("Change fired!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email">
```

Comment: Even on `keyup`, it returns 0 if only spaces are typed. But spaces in between two letters are counted. So the `value` really is trimmed... What's in field seems to be something else.

Comment: This makes sense since technically, you can't have spaces on email but on `type="text"` you can.

Comment: @TonyM: It would be a super great feature it it was also removing spaces in the middle. But not the case.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it would _**Not**_ be a super great feature to do that, since spaces _are_ legal in an email address when they are _in the correct context_. Basically _anything_ is allowed to the left of the `@` as long as it is escaped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem with React, and I don't want to reflect the error on the onBlur event (as other solutions here). I don't think an error should be reflected in any input by the simple fact of removing the mouse from that input. For me that's not User friendly,... AT ALL.

**Why?**

1. Because the User might have decided to remove the mouse from that
   Input only because he/she simply wants to copy something from somewhere else first,... and then past it there (and/or to past it somewhere else). So technically there is no mistake there yet.
2. Because I simply want to fill another input field of the form first.
   Why? Becase that's precisely the field's value I already copied from
   somewhere else, so that's the value I have stored in clipboard, and
   it doesn't goes where my mouse landed by default. Or simply because
   I just want to! I'm the User, so I can choose the order to
   fill the form!

For me is more than enough with validating what the User has written and/or removed/deleted from the Inputs (onChange validation) AND also what the User finally decides to send (onSubmit validation). A proper combination of onChange and onSubmit validation is the perfect healthy balance between thoroughness and User friendly.

**A Solomonic "solution":**

I am using a custom validation hook. As I can not change the behavior of the input with a type email regarding the white spaces in an OnChange event,... then I decided to use a workaround, which is simply avoiding the typing of white spaces and that's it, as the onChange event won't trigger anyway.

```
const preventWhiteSpaceOnKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " ") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

.
.
.

```
                <input
                    type={"email"}
                    id='commentEmail'
                    name='commentEmail'
                    required={true}
                    autoFocus={true}
                    ref={emailInputRef}
                    value={emailState}
                    onChange={emailInputChangeHandler}
                    onKeyDown={preventWhiteSpaceOnKeyDown}
                />
```

This is not a "*solution*". There is no clean solution for this. But after this at least my input[type=email] element won't hold useless white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```
$('input[type="email"]').on('focusout', {
    console.log('Triggered!');
    var $trig = $(this);
    $trig.attr('trimmed', $trig.val().toString().trim());
    $trig.val( '').val($trig.attr('trimmed'));
});
```

But, as answered above, `input[type="email"]` does not count whitespaces. It is only works as fast hack;

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who have found this issue when using react, you may want to take into consideration this appear also occurring with paste events. Building on @reinier-garcia's response above, you need to add an onPaste handler to the component to intercept this: -

```
onKeyDown={handleEmailKeyDown}
onPaste={handleEmailPaste}
```

Handlers: -

```
const handleEmailKeyDown = (e: KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  if (e.key === ' ') e.preventDefault()
}

const handleEmailPaste = (e: ClipboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  if (e.clipboardData.getData('text').trim() === '') e.preventDefault()
}
```

Note I used `trim()` is case of multiple whitespaces being pasted (very much an edge case all round).

Answer (score -2):

input[type="email"] does not fire change event, use blur event instead:

```js
$('input[type="email"]').blur(function(){
  console.log('blur event is fired.');
});
```